# Does Google Analytics track users even after UTM parameters are lost?

Tags: google-analytics

I've build links with correct UTM parameters for advertising campaigns. On the landing page, there is a download button. When the download button is clicked, the next page that loads does not retain the UTM parameters (e.g. http://example.com?utm-params-here -> http://example.com/download).

When the UTM parameters are lost as described above, does GA stop associating the user with the UTM campaign / source? Or is GA smart enough to continue associating the user with the UTM campaign / source even after the parameters are lost, as long as their initial page view on the website contains the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTM parameters for source, medium, etc. are all session-level dimensions, meaning they apply to all hits in that same session.

The only way a click on your download button wouldn't be associated with the UTM campaign / source is if a new sessions had started (for whatever reason).

You can read more about how sessions are defined here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en

Comment: Great answer Philip. A side question: I've inherited a site that has a script that keeps adding the same UTMs throughout the user's navigation on the site from URL to URL. Are there any negative side effects from doing this for GA data, Google Ads data, or elsewhere? Thanks in advance!